# Как Вывести разницу числа строк двух таблиц?

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Как с помощью  `MINUS` можно посчитать разницу таблиц. Например в таблице A 10 строк ,  в Б 5
Результат: 5

Comment: вы хотите посчитать разницу количества строк или увидеть разные строки?

Comment: MINUS возвращает строки даже если чуть чуть отличаются на одно поле. Если вам надо сравнить количества строк, то следует вычитать результаты подзапросов, получающих count() по таблицам. А если все таки нужны сами строки, то не понятно в чем состоит ваш вопрос, ибо в документации по MINUS приведены примеры использования https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Comment: Разницу количества строк нужно увидеть

Comment: тогда стоит перефразировать вопрос ибо MINUS не поможет. А нужно `select (select count(1) ... ) - (select count(1) ...) from DUAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `MINUS` нужен принципиально, то можно так

```
select count(*) from
(
  select rownum from a 
  minus 
  select rownum from b
)
```

Но если в А меньше строк, то этот запрос выведет 0.

---

Если, всё-таки отрицательная разница тоже нужна, то можно как-то так

```
select sum(cnt) from
(
  select count(*) cnt from
  (
    select rownum from a 
    minus 
    select rownum from b
  )
  union
  select count(*) *-1 from
  (
    select rownum from b 
    minus 
    select rownum from a
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select (select count(1) from A) - (select count(1) from B) from dual
```